# How to set a auto-increment value in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, python, orm, sqlalchemy

This is my code :

```
    class csvimportt(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'csvimportt'

      #id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
      aid = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True, zerofill=True),
          Sequence('article_aid_seq', start=1001, increment=1),
          primary_key=True)
```

I want to set a autoincrement value from 1000. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Starting from version 1.4, SQLAlechemy has `Identity` column.

Example copied from [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-10-and-above-identity-columns):

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, MetaData, Integer, Identity

metadata = MetaData()

data = Table(
    "data",
    metadata,
    Column(
        'id', Integer, Identity(start=42, cycle=True), primary_key=True
    ),
    Column('data', String)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

[From the SQLAlchemy 1.2 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sequences-serial-identity):

> Postgresql 10 has a new IDENTITY feature that supersedes the use of SERIAL. ***Built-in support for rendering of IDENTITY is not available yet***, however the following compilation hook may be used to replace occurrences of SERIAL with IDENTITY:
>
> ```
> from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateColumn
> from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
>
>
> @compiles(CreateColumn, 'postgresql')
> def use_identity(element, compiler, **kw):
>     text = compiler.visit_create_column(element, **kw)
>     text = text.replace("SERIAL", "INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY")
>     return text
> ```